# How to change the color of the labels in matlab

Tags: matlab, label

i want to know how to change the color of the labels, basically if you're going to plot and put labels automatically the color of the labels are black but i want to change it to different color (for example red)

example of labels:

```
A = {'apple'
'red'
'orange'}
```

so what do you think guys? thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have there is a cell array, it doesn't have colors, not even black. What colors are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that X and Y labels?

```
xlabel ( 'Apple', 'Color', 'red' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes `xlabel` doesn't work well and you want to customize your plots.

this code always works but is manual

```
distr=figure;
xlabel(strcat('\bf Aperture a=^~',num2str(r_aper/lambda,2),...
   '\lambda')); ylabel('\bf E_a(r)');
xmin=0; xmax=1; ymin=0; ymax=1;
axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax]);
set(gca,'FontSize',9);
set(gca,'xTickMode','Manual');
set(gca,'xTickLabelMode','Manual');
set(gca,'XTick',[0 .125 .25 .375 .5 .625 .75 .875 1]);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'0'; ' '; 'a/4' ; ' '; 'a/2'; ' ';'3a/4'; ' ';'a'});
set(gcf,'Color',[0.4,0.6,0.99]);
```